# Is there an elegant way with React-Router to clear the current component's rendered data, when one of its routes are matched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component called PastIssues, which lists all of the past editions of a magazine. The output of the component is an ordered list where each item is the year of release followed by the season. For example:

1. Spring:2014
2. Autumn:2015

Each of these items is a Link that points to a specific path. I've dynamically added  to this component, such that my ShowArticleInfo component will be displayed. My issue lies, when the user clicks one of the Links, my ShowArticleInfo component gets rendered, but only below ordered list. I would like my ordered list to disappear, such that the only remaining component is ShowArticleInfo.

So before the user clicks anything, I want a list of links, one for each article (in the example above). After a user clicks one of them, I want the list to disappear and only ShowArticleInfo to appear.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: You're talking about conditional rendering... It's impossible to help you without any sample code... please see how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Use local storage to set a key with value true

```
   componentDidMount(){
   localStorage.setItem('loaded','true');
   }
```

and clear local storage when u unmount component ShowArticleInfo.
In your ordered list component render.

```
   render(){
         let loaded = localStorage.getItem('loaded');
         return(
               <div style={{display:{loaded ==='true' ? 'none':'block'}}>
               </div>
             )
           }
```

For further info on localstorage  **[MDN/localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**.